# Issue Trying To Access Kubernetes API from Docker Container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes

I am facing issue. I am trying to access Kubernetes API from Docker Container (Created .NetCore). I am getting Error Message **"Connection Refused"**.

Can anyone help?
I shall be thankful.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
  var request_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj).ToString();
  var content = new StringContent(request_json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Token");
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("close");
  var result = await client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:8001/apis/batch/v1/namespaces/default", content);
  var result_string = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`enter code here`;
  return result_string.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your docker container is running inside a kubernetes cluster, you can access the kubernetes API through a service. In the default namespace the service is already provided as `kubernetes`, so the connection url would be `https://kubernetes/`.

If you are running the docker container locally and want to use the `kubectl proxy` to access the kubernetes api the docker container must be running without network isolation in order to be able to access the local proxy port: `docker run --net=host`. This only works if you are using linux, on MacOS or Windows a virtual machine is used to host the docker containers and `localhost` is then the VM, not your desktop. You would then use one of the special host names `docker.for.mac.host.internal` or `docker.for.win.localhost`, but you will need to launch the kubectl-proxy accordingly to listen not only on the loopback network interface, since the request will come from the docker-vm, which is external.

BTW: If you are using kubectl-proxy, it will automatically authenticate the requests and there is no need to add a bearer token.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I think this will resolve my issue, All I need to do just deploy container on same cluster where kubernetes is running.